# PHP - Export as Tab Separated with New Lines

Tags: php

I have an array like so

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        [0] => 204-7523179-7900317-A4WhiteFramedPrint
        [1] => A4 White Framed Print
        [2] => 21M
        [3] => Daddy
        [4] => Love Kieran & Mason Xxx
    )

    [1] => Array
        (
        [0] => 204-7523179-7900317-A4WhiteFramedPrint
        [1] => A4 Black Framed Print
        [2] => 21M
        [3] => Mummy
        [4] => Love Bob Xxx
    )
}
```

I am trying to export this to a Tab Seperated File (TSV) which i do with

```
header('Content-type: text/tab-separated-values');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=file.txt");
foreach ($array as $fields) {
    echo implode("\t",$fields);
}
```

This works fine and seperates the array values with a tab, however there is no new lines, the first array's values are shown within the txt file and then a long space followed by the next array's values (on same line).

I want to have each array on a new line within the text file if possible, i have tried adding in a `echo "\n"` or `PHP_EOL` etc but none of this works.

Any help would be appriciated thanks.

Comment: echo "\n\r"; inside the foreach. Did you try?

Comment: Where did you add the `PHP_EOL` that should have worked. `echo implode("\t",$fields) . PHP_EOL;`

Comment: Adding echo "\n\r"; or the PHP_EOL within the foreach does not work, txt file still shows all on one line

Comment: Actually your headers are sending a file, but you dont appear to be writing to a file???

Comment: Just echoing out the data goes into the txt file correctly, just doesn't add new line

Answer (score 0):

You need to implode the main array with `\n`

```
$array = [
    [
        '204-7523179-7900317-A4WhiteFramedPrint',
        'A4 White Framed Print',
        '21M',
        'Daddy',
        'Love Kieran & Mason Xxx',
    ], [
        'A4 White Framed Print',
        '21M',
        'Mummy',
        'Love Bob Xxx',
    ]
];

foreach ($array as $key => $fields) {
    $array[$key] = implode("\t",$fields);
}
echo implode("\n", $array);
```

Comment: Still does not move to a new line in the downloaded txt file

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the newline after each `implode` call!

```
<?php

$array = [
    [
    'A4 White Framed Print',
    '21M',
    'Daddy',
    'Love Kieran & Mason Xxx',
    ],
    [
    'A4 White Framed Print',
    '21M',
    'Mummy',
    'Love Bob Xxx',
    ]
];

foreach ($array as $subArray) {
    echo implode("\t", $subArray);
    echo "\n";
}
```

https://eval.in/1014723

Comment: Have tried this already. Does not move to a new line in the exported txt file

Comment: Try it with actually downloading the txt file

Comment: Here's a screencast of just that: https://gfycat.com/DirtyHiddenFirefly

Comment: One more quick sanity test – gdrive seems to know what to do with it: https://gfycat.com/WelloffHardtofindFruitbat

Comment: Seemed to have been a problem with notepad, opening it up in notepad++ showed the new lines

Comment: Cool! I wonder if you might mark my answer as "accepted", if you find it to be correct, then?

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

Using your example:

```
<?php
$array = array(
    array('204-7523179-7900317-A4WhiteFramedPrint', 'A4 White Framed Print', '21M', 'Daddy','Love Kieran & Mason Xxx'),
    array('204-7523179-7900317-A4WhiteFramedPrint','A4 Black Framed Print','21M','Mummy','Love Bob Xxx')
);

header('Content-type: text/tab-separated-values');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=file.txt");
foreach ($array as $fields) {
    echo implode("\t",$fields).PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

With generated file:

```
<?php
$array = array(
    array('204-7523179-7900317-A4WhiteFramedPrint', 'A4 White Framed Print', '21M', 'Daddy','Love Kieran & Mason Xxx'),
    array('204-7523179-7900317-A4WhiteFramedPrint','A4 Black Framed Print','21M','Mummy','Love Bob Xxx')
);

$filename = 'csv-file.txt';
$file = fopen($filename, "w");
foreach ($array as $fields) {
    fwrite($file, implode("\t",$fields).PHP_EOL);
}
fclose($file);

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-type: text/tab-separated-values');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($filename).'"');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
readfile($filename);
exit;
?>
```

Tested on Apache 2.2 (Windows 10) and IIS 10 (Windows 10).